# Time series forecasting with incomplete future data

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have historical daily time series bookings data. I am using the Prophet model to predict daily bookings for the next 7 days. However,  I also have incomplete booking information for future dates.
How do I take into account this incomplete or imperfect future information in my prediction?

Comment: May I suggest you pose a [minimally reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It is too easy to forget this is the [value of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), data in provides data out. Adding a snippet of code and a minimal dataset allows more intelligent discussions. 'Without data, you're just another person with an opinion.'